# ls: reading directory ./: Input/output error via S3FS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I have a bucket with more than ten thousand files. I am getting the following error while doing 'ls -l' folder but working fine for less than 1000 files in the folder. Any suggestions?

ls: reading directory ./: Input/output error

I notice that each listing of a file in folder makes an http call to S3, any chance this # can be increased?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid such abusive situations and use sub-directories in S3

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to take a look at the new project RioFS (Userspace S3 filesystem): https://github.com/skoobe/riofs.

This project is “s3fs” alternative, the main advantages comparing to “s3fs” are: simplicity, the speed of operations and bugs-free code. Currently [the project](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) is in the “testing” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time.

We are seeking for more people to join our project and help with the testing. From our side we offer quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

[RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) should work fine with such great number of files per directory, but please try to increase the directory caching timeout in the configuration file (see `dir_cache_max_time` description in `riofs.conf.xml`)

Hope it helps you and we are looking forward to seeing you joined our community !